# Where are ssh login attempts logged to on jailbroken iPhone with OpenSSH?

Tags: jailbreak, ssh, logs, iphone

I know in Ubuntu they are in /var/log/auth.log but I can't find where they are logged on the iPhone. Ive made sure logging is enabled and have looked in /var/log and /var/logs as well as pretty much everywhere. Still cant find where the attempts are being logged.

Comment: I've looked everywhere, and I can't find any log file for `sshd`.

Comment: Same here. It seems as if maybe there isn't a log...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer to this

you have to manually edit `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist`

change this part:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
    <string>-i</string>
</array>
```

to this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/sshd</string>
    <string>-E /var/log/auth.log -i</string>
</array>
```

then reboot or restart sshd

Comment: Nice! I sold my iPhone so I chalked it up as a lost cause, but still this is very useful.